# how to enable tap option in my timelinetime

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have a timelineitem, lets take it as **start timeline**.
Now I want to enable **tap option** or **tap functionality** on start timeline.
After tapping I want to open **bundle of timeline** such as 3 or 4 timeline.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **start timeline** and each timeline in the **bundle of timeline** are HTML, you can use pagination.

You can do this by inserting 1 item into the timeline with multiple article tags. The first article tag will be what shows in the timeline and the other article tags will open on tap of the cover.  Use `class="cover-only"` if you don't want the cover to show in the opened items.

e.g.

```
<article class="cover-only>
  <section>
    <h1>This is where start timeline will go</h1>
  </section>
</article>
<article>
  <section>
    <h1>This will show first when the "start timeline" item is tapped</h1>
  </section>
</article>
<article>
  <section>
    <h1>This will show when swiping from the first bundled timeline item</h1>
  </section>
</article>
```

If your timeline items aren't HTML, you can use bundle IDs.

Insert all your timeline items individually, but give them the same value for `bundleId`.  Then give **start timeline** a value of `true` for `isBundleCover`.